# How to test logic apps using SpecFlow when Logic app trigger is Http Request?

Tags: c#, azure, specflow, azure-logic-apps

I have `already gone through` this article of [Michael Stephenson](http://www.integrationusergroup.com/automated-testing-logic-apps-specflow/)
`automated-testing-logic-apps-specflow`

My `Logicapp triggers with Http Request` I wonder how can I write test case using `SpecFLow` library .

I tried few steps like below but how can I trigger its very first step?

```
@dev
Scenario: WhiteboxTest - Process Topic Message - Yes
    Given the storage account is empty
    | Storage account |
    | mydemo |
    And the logic app is enabled
    When a message is submitted to the topic
    | Topic |
    | TestTopic |
    Then the logic app will receive the message
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the logic of invoke by HTTP your Logic App URL with a helper class in C#, ... as in the article of Michael Stephenson did publishing a new message on the queue.

Comment: oh got it I can do it by using HttpClient and execute logic app post url with data, is that you suggest ? Actually I was looking something with SpecFlow because where I can write that Http trigger logic in feature file? at very first I need to do it. is it correct way?

Comment: In my blog is the full example for that post of Michael Stephenson http://felixmondelo.blogspot.com.es/2017/04/automated-testing-logic-apps-with.html

Comment: Thanks : ) but why only test is for queue ? not for xml validation ?

Comment: Because is a little more complex, with the use of LogAnalytics, ... And I never finished the part 2 of that post :-(

Comment: ohh it will be great help for everyone if you able to share it. or any link

Comment: it will be great help for everyone if you share it :) or post any other link for the same kind of scenarios

Comment: any help on this questions if you can , how to set environment variable for deployment ? How to avoid hardcore values instead use parameters ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213470/how-to-use-deployment-environment-inside-unit-test-project-for-specflow-logic-ap